# Client requesting artwork file for print production

Tags: print-design, client-relations

I have recently completed a package design for a client.

He has now asked for the artwork file (AI) so the printers can set up the dye cut etc, he has specified the need for all artwork included.

My question is should I hand it over or is there an alternative as I don't want them to have the ability to alter my design without my consent as well as if changes are needed in the future I want them to be coming to me for it.

Comment: Hi user122812, the work of the graphic designer is not only the design but also includes the prepress, explaining this to your client, you can not ask the printing contact to deal directly with them about the files changes?

Comment: This [question/answers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/41228/120647) can help.

Comment: Your contact and licensing option should handle the issue of them not altering your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Keep The Clients Happy :)

Ideally, you should have an agreement that both you and the client signed detailing the terms of the contract. This is to prevent these types of situations.

If you don't have a contract, then the client has no right to the files unless a court determines there is enough evidence that they have entitlement.

However, I would recommend handing all the files over. It's better business practice to keep clients happy. They might even recommend you if you do.

However, if you think you might suffer loses by handing the files over, you could hand them over with terms. Most clients would be more than pleased to accept this.

### Alternatively

Alternatively, you could flatten the image so it's not editable and export to the correct format and size for printing, which doesn't have to be an AI file.

Comment: Thank you yes makes sense what you are saying, I do not have a contract with him but think I might drop him an email stating terms of use etc. I can't flatten it and give it to them as they need to alter it in AI for print set up I believe

Comment: Good luck - I hope it all works out :)

Comment: If you found this answer informative enough, please consider marking it as the answer :)

Comment: Just to follow up on this see from client...... " Following on from your mail we will be using the files to be sent onto the printers. Some resizing and other minor amendments may need to be carried out in order to fit the curve of the die lines etc. Please ensure you send all the files in editable format and include all assets (e.g all images etc used). Once files have been transferred, ownership is transferred to Company name. and you (My name) will not be liable for any errors in the artwork.

Comment: Is that a response you’re happy with?

Comment: Sorry meant to add, no not really as it is still under my ownership as a designer.. am I not correct in thinking that

Comment: Yes. I know how frustrating it is. I've been in a similar situation a few times, we feel so proud of our work we don't want to let it go. Emotions vs business, they never mix. When I was younger, emotions won, but now I'm a bit older in the tooth, business wins. I've learned to let go - almost ;)

Comment: Yes exactly that haha, so you reckon thats fine etc I just don't want him to legally be able to outsource more designs for different flavours using my AI file as the template, does that make sense?

Comment: 99.999% It's fine. I never had an issue. Companies are often very policy driven in a "holier than thou" way. It's just one of those things. If you did have issues down the line, where they are abusing your trust or copyright, it's better to challenge it then. And always good to remember, no matter how clever their wording, they can't make you sign away your statutory rights :)